# Why do we use $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and $(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$ from tangent vectors in Polar Coordinates?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

> Why do we use $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and $(-\sin\theta,
>  \cos\theta)$ as tangent vectors from Polar Coordinates?

The picture makes sense, but from differential manifold's point of view, given the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^2$, we have two global charts given by 
$f:{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where 
$$f=id =(x,y),$$ and $g:{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where 
$$g(m_1, m_2)=(\sqrt{m_1^2 + m_2^2},\arctan(m_2/m_1)) = (r,\theta).$$

Let $\partial_{r_1}=(1,0), \partial_{r_2}=(0,1)$ be the canonical tangent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the tangent vectors on $(M,f=(x,y))$ are 
$$\partial_x = df^{-1}(\partial_{r_1}) = (1,0)$$
$$\partial_y = df^{-1}(\partial_{r_2}) = (0,1)$$
The tangent vectors on $(M,g=(r,\theta))$ are
$$\partial_r = dg^{-1}(\partial_{r_1}) = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$$
$$\partial_\theta = dg^{-1}(\partial_{r_2}) = (-r\sin\theta, r\sin\theta)$$

And most calculus books use $e_r = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, $e_\theta =  (-\sin\theta, \sin\theta)$, why can we just drop the factor $r$ in $e_\theta$? 
And the gradient, divergence, flux formula are given in this basis too...

Shouldn't it be more natural to keep the $r$. For example if we have a vector field $v$ in $(M,f)$, and we would like to do a change of coordinate to polar, the new vector field in $(M,g)$ is just given by 
$$\tilde v = d(g^{-1} \circ f) v = \tilde v_1 \partial_r + \tilde v_2 \partial_\theta$$
and the divergence in polar 
$$div(\tilde v) = \frac{\partial \tilde v_1}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial \tilde v_2}{\partial \theta}.$$

If we drop the $r$ in $e_\theta$, I believe we have this complicated formula
$$div(\bar v) = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r\bar v_1}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \bar v_2}{\partial \theta}.$$

Comment: Use whichever vectors you like, but $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ are orthogonal unit vectors, which is convenient.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but it seems like the divergence formula is more complicated...

Comment: @Xiao: The divergence is even more complicated if you use $\partial_r, \partial_{\theta}, \partial_{z}$ instead of $e_r,e_{\theta},e_z$ because you need to replace $\tilde{v_2}$ by $\frac{\tilde{v_2}}{r}$...

Comment: If you know differential forms, they give the least painful way to derive the formulas for grad, curl, and div in different coordinate systems. When you want to figure out the Hodge star operator, you see the importance of orthonormal bases (and dual bases).